# Add delay or pause to MySQL query for security

Tags: php, mysql, security

I've been reading up on security measures to prevent brute force attacks.  I'm specifically concerned with querying my MySQL database through PHP.

Is there a way to add a pause in the MySQL query of a few seconds, either through PHP or MySQL?  This would limit the number of brute force attempts a hacker could use.

For reference, I found the idea here - http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks

Comment: I doubt a few seconds would make much difference, unless the delay increased over how many times the SQL was queried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing Brute Force Logins on Websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424210/preventing-brute-force-logins-on-websites)

Answer (score 2):

You can do usleep or sleep as the other said, but this is not how this security measure should be implemented. Actually these functions are useless for this model of security. What you want is to add a logic layer to the login function that will check for a given user the number of logins or some timeframe. Delaying the execution of the script makes no sense as a new request will start another php script. Check for timestamp of the last login attempt from that IP or log the number of tries and if you decide there is a risk just block the requests from that IP for the next 24 hours or so.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of anything from the MySQL side, but from a PHP script, you can use the sleep or usleep functions to pause the execution of your scripts.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php

Sleep will pause for the defined number of seconds.

usleep will pause for the defined number of microseconds. This gives you a much more precise level of delay, so I would use this instead.

Therefore, usleep is more appropriate, so you could do something like this.

```
// your php code here
// then wait for 1.1 second
usleep(1001000);
// then do your SQL stuff
```

I would caution the use of this though. The user experience will suffer as a result, as your pages will be slower to respond. Maybe have a function that only resorts to using delays if you see an abnormal spike in traffic, or a lot of traffic from one source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function to do this. Of course, you only want to do this if the authentication fails.

Answer (score 0):

If brute force is an issue use a Captcha like [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).  You don't have to prompt them right away,  like gmail you can wait until they build up enough "heat".   You can store heat in the database and address it to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.  The use of `$_SESSION` would be weak because the attacker can just grab a fresh session id.