# Why blocking the user, not the IP when fail to login?

Tags: php, security

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424210/preventing-brute-force-logins-on-websites) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798918/what-is-the-best-method-to-prevent-a-brute-force-attack) that tracking the failed login attempts should be done on the user.

"If *anyone* tries to log in with the username/email
`somone@example.com` X wrong times. I block `somone@example.com`"

**Why shouldn't I do this based on IP ?** as anyone can block my users by knowing only their usernames/emails. Why shouldn't I do it like :

"If *this IP* tries to log in with *any* username/email X wrong times. I block this IP" ?

Comment: IP can be spoofed. Some workplaces, schools etc, you also might have many many people coming from the same public IP.

Comment: IP != user, 1 person many IP's. one IP many people

Comment: There are thousands of users who could log in from the same Microsoft.com IP address. Do you ban all MS employees from your site because one may have done something wrong?

Comment: @ficuscr So, how to protect my users from getting blocked if someone knows their username ?

Comment: imo with security, fraud prevention etc, the more layers and combinations of approaches the better. 80/20. There are a number of ways to prevent brute force attacks. CAPTCHA after x failures, force strong password. Don't bother with locking accounts.

Comment: Blocking IP makes sense e.g. for malicious webbots coming repeatedly from the same IP. Users may login each day from different computer, meaning also different IP.

Comment: i run a few sites, i dont block based on ip or failed attempt. its certainly not compulsory - and as you see has some huge issues

Comment: ^ agreed, are you making your users safer or just inconveniencing them (false positive of valid user failing to recall password) and creating a support nightmare?

Comment: I voted to close, this is opinion based. with a *incorrect* underlying assumption that you even have to block any one for any reason.

Comment: @smith *"with a incorrect underlying assumption that you even have to block any one for any reason"* do you mean I shouldn't block a user when there is too many failed login attempts ?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good example is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AOL#Why_are_AOL_users_often_blocked?

IPs don't identify a single person. ISPs, large corporations, public spots like libraries, etc will often use some kind of enforced proxy, NAT, or transparent caching host for outgoing connections. This makes all the users from that network share a single IP.

Blocking the IP because of one person can block the whole group.

Comment: Thank you very much, but doen't this make it very easy for an attacker to repeatedly block my users if he knows their username ?

Comment: Yes. That's why locking out in general is a bad idea. There are better solutions, like giving your users the 2FA options, so even bruteforcing the password doesn't give the access. Optionally you could block a (username,ip) pair for a short time (minutes) or adding some client-side work factor to slow down the attacker.

Answer (score 0):

Ips are generally dynamically assigned, so blocking a black hat one day maybe blocking a white hat the next

Comment: thank you very much, I will block for temporarily time off curse

Comment: no 'black hat' uses their own IP, and nor would they use just one